# A question regarding equations of motion

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics

Suppose I drop a body from a height $h$. The initial velocity is zero. Now it reaches the ground and stops and finally becomes zero. So now u=0 and v=0. If I use the equation of motion $v=u+at$ to find value of acceleration and input u=0 and v=0 I get a=0 even though it is clearly wrong and there was acceleration due to gravity. So what is going on here? Where is my understanding going wrong?

Comment: The equations you’re using work only for *constant* acceleration, but the acceleration changes the moment the body hits the ground, so you can only use the kinematic equations until the moment just before the body hits the ground.

Comment: @march In the future, please post answers as answers, not as comments

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The equations of motion only work for constant acceleration. The setup mentioned in your question doesn’t satisfy that criteria. You can use the equations of motion to model the motion of the body right from the instant of time you drop it, to the instant of time right before it hits the ground/zero level. In this period of time, the acceleration is constant (almost constant) and the equations of motion hold. However, after hitting the ground, energy is lost to heat, friction, sound, and other forms of energy transfer take place. Also, the ground exerts a force on the body. All this is to say that the value of acceleration is no longer constant, and the equations of motion no longer hold.

Answer (score 2):

v=0 after it hits the ground,SUVAT only applies when acceleration is uniform, when it hits the ground acceleration must change from 9.81 to something else, because there is now a new force acting on the object: the normal contact force. From F=ma, a change in the resultant force acting on an object (while mass is constant) means that acceleration must also change.
(This is a bit sidetracked from what you were asking, but I hope that gives some context for what's next)

Since we've established that a must be constant when the body is falling, v is the value *before* it hits the ground. Usually its the maximum/ terminal velocity the body can reach - which is often not 0! Hence the problem isn't with your acceleration value of g=9.81 when falling, its with the value of final velocity.

Answer (score 0):

The body's motion has two very different parts: It begins by accelerating down, until just before reaching the ground. At this point, as you noted, its velocity will be $v=-g*t$ (if the acceleration due to the earth gravitation is $-g$) and you can calculate this $t$ using the equation for the displacement in your case (with $x=h$, $v_0=0$) $-h = 1/2 g t^2$.

So far the equations will fit very well.

But, when the body hits the ground at the calculated speed, as you know it will have to stop... An elastic body will actually jump up and down a few times, losing a bit of the energy to heat. An inelastic body will lose all the energy almost at once to heat. Eventually, perhaps after a couple of small jumps, the body will settle down on the ground with velocity 0. But you can't use the equation for free fall at a constant acceleration to calculate that.